# Fill pandas DF column with condition of np.where() - works without where, doesn't work with

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I've got a list of email recipients - half of them are styled

```
 "Firstname Lastname" <firstname.lastname@email.com>
```

And half are styled

```
 firstname.lastname@email.com [some text goes here asdfsdafasgawgaw etc]
```

I've got the data in a separate DF, split() from a different set of data.

when I do

```
 df_task_email['contents'] = df_email_contents.iloc[:,0]
```

It just works (copying the contents of the email to the column)

when I do

```
 df_task_email['to_name'] = np.where(
    df_split3.iloc[:,0].str.startswith('\"'),

    #True - copy contents of cell across
    df_split3.iloc[:,0].str.replace("\"","").replace(np.nan,'',regex=True),

    #False - extract the first email address - "pattern" is the regex for an email 
    df_split3.iloc[:,0].str.extract(pattern)[0].replace(np.nan,'',regex=True)
)
```

I get

```
  > ValueError: Length of values (37099) does not match length of index (2010634)
```

(If the index is too long for np.where(), why is it not too long for just "="?)

As a test, if I remove the np.where() and just set

```
 df_task_email['to_name'] = df_split3.iloc[:,0].str.replace("\"","").replace(np.nan,'',regex=True),
```

Then it works again (although it didn't process the data like I expected it to

Comment: do each of the 3 arguments to `np.where` run correctly each by themselves?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `.str.extract()` to get the email from the `contents` column ([regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MR3915/1)):

Consider this dataframe:

```
                                                                  contents
0                   "Firstname1 Lastname2" <firstname1.lastname@email.com>
1  firstname.lastname@email.com [some text goes here asdfsdafasgawgaw etc]
2                   "Firstname3 Lastname4" <firstname2.lastname@email.com>
```

Then:

```py
df["email"] = df["contents"].str.extract(r"\" <([^>]+)>|(^\S+) \[").bfill(axis=1)[0]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                                                  contents                          email
0                   "Firstname1 Lastname2" <firstname1.lastname@email.com>  firstname1.lastname@email.com
1  firstname.lastname@email.com [some text goes here asdfsdafasgawgaw etc]   firstname.lastname@email.com
2                   "Firstname3 Lastname4" <firstname2.lastname@email.com>  firstname2.lastname@email.com
```